# simple use recordset to find text box value on report

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

I'm trying to learn how to use recordsets in VBA and starting here.  I want to lookup the value from the ProductVars table and populate to a text box on a report for each record [ProductID].

The value I want is where Field [Name]="Hinging" and I need it to send the value from the Field [Value] to the txtHinge text box on the report.

Here is my current code.

```
Private Sub Report_Load()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb

'Open a table-type Recordset
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("ProductVars")

'Find the value of Hinging from the Name field Name and populate to txtHinge 
for the ProductID

Do Until rs.EOF
Me.txtHinge = rs!Name.Hinging.Value
rs.MoveNext
Loop

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Image of ProductVars table]

Comment: Your code has numerous oddities and things that will generate compile errors. You probably shouldn't be doing this in VBA at all, and modify the reports record source or text box's control source instead.

Comment: Typically I would do this as a DLookup in the control source of a report but I have another situation with conditional statements where DLookup doesn't work so I'm trying to learn about recordsets instead.   
 This is just a starting point.  Any suggestions of the best way to learn this @ErikvonAsmuth?

Comment: Name and Value are special words in Access/VBA. Advise not to use them as names for anything. Cannot dynamically set the value of textbox on report in the Load event. A function could be called from textbox ControlSource to return a value. And this means a DLookup should be able to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Edit question to show the report RecordSource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In textbox ControlSource:

`=DLookup("[Value]", "PRODUCTVARS", "[Name]='Hinging' AND ProductID=" & [ProductID])`

Or if multiple dynamic parameters must be considered:

`=DLookup("[Value]", "PRODUCTVARS", "[Name]='" & [Name] & "' AND ProductID=" & [ProductID])`

If the latter is the case, possibly could just include the PRODUCTVARS table in the report RecordSource with a compound join.

Comment: This first option worked for my report.  Thanks!  Btw, you mentioned to add it to the ControlSource but what if I wanted to add it to VBA?  I tried 
       Me!.txtHinge.Value = DLookup("[Value]", "PRODUCTVARS", "[Name]='Hinging' AND ProductID=" & [ProductID])      but that didn't work.

Comment: Cannot set the Value property of textbox in report with VBA.